# ora-24399- Invalid number of connections specified -OCCI program

Tags: c++, c, oracle, occi

I am using following simple code to connect to database and I am getting error as ORA-24399 which says invalid number of connections specified. I have googled enough but not clue. This is a CPP program.

Following is code Snippet:

```
try
{
        Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
        Connection *con= env->createConnection("test","test","testdb");
}
catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        cout<<ex.getMessage().c_str();
    }
```

P.S Using SQL Plus I am able to connect to the database where this code is being run. There are no issues there. Only through program there is a failure seen.

P.P.S Tried using connectionpool as well but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your [error](http://ora-24399.ora-code.com/), it seems that the problem is somewhere else in your code: you should fix the parameters (related to connection numbers) in the call to `OCIConnectionPoolCreate`.

Comment: Ya I agree...but my code is that much only..this function is just inside a main() nothing else....

Comment: Maybe[createConnectionPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28390/reference014.htm#i1090287) is more appropriate ?